# Como minimizar problemas de migração mysql 4 para o 5

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Boa noite pessoal, tenho um sistema que foi desenvolvido ano passado para um cliente.
O cliente contratou um servidor e o pessoal instalou o mysql 5 nele.

O problema agora que estou é que campo int e date que vão vazios na query do cadastro da o seguinte erro:

Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id_producao' at row 1

O grande problema é que são campos não obrigatorios do usuario no sistema, alguem já passou por isso e conseguiu resolver?